# Add string url inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a url as string :-
`url='https://www.business-standard.com/article/technology/xiaomi-mi-a2-india-launch-today-how-to-watch-livestream-know-specs-price-118080800144_1.html'`.

I want to add this url into pandas dataframe as text'.
All I did as:-

```
data=pd.DataFrame(url,columns=['url'])
```

It gives error as:

> ValueError:DataFrame constructor not properly called!

I don't get it where I did wrong?

Expected output :

```
url
https://www.business-standard.com/article/technology/xiaomi-mi-a2-india-launch-today-how-to-watch-livestream-know-specs-price-118080800144_1.html
........................
........................
.......................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert string to one element list by `[]`:

```
data=pd.DataFrame([url],columns=['url'])
print (data)
                                                 url
0  https://www.business-standard.com/article/tech...
```